# Facebook meta tags not working for AJAX website

Tags: html, ajax, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have a 100% ajax webapp and I have the following problem.
My site generates dynamic content, and I have a like button for each ajax "page"
generated dynamically. To be clear, he links are "...#subpage", and a user can put like on
"...#subpage". However, I would like a preview of that content to be available.

I have put the apropriate meta tags (og:image, og:url, etc.) However, in the 
 facebook link debugger (http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) It always says that the tags are in their initial state (as in just the plain html page, no ajax).

So question is, how to make the meta tags work dyamically for facebook links

Comment: You will need to make the meta tags dynamic with server side code such as php or aspx.  The issue is ajax is client side and most web spiders including facebook's do not run and render javascript they only read the meta and html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's best to actually give the pages their own URL. You can use server side methods like `.htaccess` to redirect a URL like `http://yourdomain.com/birds/bees` to `http://yourdomain.com?page=birds&subpage=bees`. That way your content becomes searchable, accessible and bookmarkable.

You can use the HTML5 history API (http://html5demos.com/history) to update the address bar with the current URL without reloading the page. You can also attach an event to the back button, which makes your site even more user-friendly.

When you update the address bar, you can use Javascript to update the meta tags too, so the Facebook like button will like the 'correct' page.

The HTML5 History API works in all modern browsers, Internet Explorer is the only unsupported browser.

Comment: Great answer, thanks, but, if I'm not mistaken, search engines tend to downgrade pages whit a lot of redirects. Does this apply here?

Comment: Not at all. It's a server-side redirect, so the user is shown the page without the URL changing. The 'redirect' part occurs before the page is sent to the browser, so there's no effect on SEO.